# Is this sentence grammatically correct or not? I need help

Tags: grammar

> I don't know if I will have anything to write about.

Is this sentence grammatically correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's certainly grammatically correct. Let's invent a context for it:

> You're pretty good with words. Why don't you become a writer?

> OK, but here's the problem.
> I don't know if I will have anything to write about.